# Как продолжить обучение модели?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

Предположим я тренировал модель таким образом:

```
filename = 'model.h5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filename, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 100, batch_size=256, validation_data=(testX, testY), callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Она сохранена в model.h5.

Как я могу начать тренировать ее еще раз, но чтобы прогресс с предыдущего раза сохранялся?

То есть чтобы:

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 100, batch_size=256, validation_data=(testX, testY), callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

и еще раз:

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 100, batch_size=256, validation_data=(testX, testY), callbacks=[checkpoint]
```

былo равносильно:

```
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs = 200, batch_size=256, validation_data=(testX, testY), callbacks=[checkpoint]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы запустите `model.fit()` второй раз после окончания работы первого запуска `model.fit()`, то модель *продолжит обучение*. Текущее состояние модели, включая все веса и атрибуты, хранится в памяти. Соответственно если Python был рестартован, то сохраненную модель надо предварительно загрузить в память:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('/path/to/saved_model')
```

в этом случае в память загрузится состояние модели, которое было последним сохранено во время `checkpoint`, т.е. с лучшим показателем `val_loss`.

Answer (score 0):

Код для выполнения этих шагов может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
# Шаг 1: Подготовка данных
# Собираем набор изображений и их меток, где метки представляют собой контуры на изображениях
# Шаг 2: Разделение данных на обучающую и тестовую выборки
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
# Шаг 3: Подготовка изображений
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
# Приводим все изображения к одному размеру
img_size = (100, 100)
X_train_resized = []
for img in X_train:
    img_resized = resize(img, img_size)
    X_train_resized.append(img_resized)
X_train_resized = np.array(X_train_resized)
# Нормализуем значения пикселей в диапазон от 0 до 1
X_train_normalized = X_train_resized / 255.0
# Шаг 4: Создание модели нейронной сети
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_size[0], img_size[1], 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Шаг 5: Обучение модели
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train_normalized, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
# Шаг 6: Оценка модели
X_test_resized = []
for img in X_test:
   img_resized = resize(img, img_size)
   X_test_resized.append(img_resized)
X_test_resized = np.array(X_test_resized)
X_test_normalized = X_test_resized / 255.0
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test_normalized, y_test)
print('Test accuracy:', test_acc)
# Шаг 7: Использование модели
new_image = # загрузить новое изображение
new_image_resized = resize(new_image, img_size)
new_image_normalized = new_image_resized / 255.0
predicted_contours = model.predict(new_image_normalized)
```